# OpenVPN client accessible from WAN on Asus Router

Tags: routing, iptables, openvpn

I have Asus RT-N66U router with enabled OpenVPN server. I need to make one port of the connected OpenVPN client available from the Internet. So I want to forward port 80 to the device connected via OpenVPN to my router.

First I tried to TUN configuration. Client has IP adress 10.8.0.5. I forwarded port 80 to 10.8.0.5

Problem is that it works just from the internal LAN. I can also use external IP address and normally forward all the packets to the 10.8.0.5 to the client, but from the Internet I always get timeout, it looks that packets arrive to device but response not.

I tried to manually modify iptables according to the https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting and nothing helps.

Now I reconfigured OpenVPN to used TAP. And again the same it fully works from the LAN, but not from the Internet. There must be something that I miss.

Here is list of all iptables rules for booth configurations https://gist.github.com/tprochazka/72b5ca9b686d20b200c5f2662d0e9db8 (IP tables is generated by router itself)

Can someone tell me what prevents traffic from eth0 to tun/tap interface in booth ways?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by “make one port of the connected OpenVPN client available from the Internet”? What OpenVPN client? Is all traffic from said client tunneled through the VPN? By “from LAN” and “from Internet” do you mean from behind the router and elsewhere?

Comment: OpenVPN client is technically Raspbery Pi, connected to some free WIFI hotspot without a public IP address. I need to access it over the Internet. So it is connected to my Asus Router through OpenVPN. And I can fully access it in my local network. But now I need to make one port of the RPI accessible from Internet (forward port 80 from my router to RPI over OpenVPN)

Comment: I normally configure Port Forwarding on my router to any device directly in my local network. It always works from the Internet. Only problem is now with the OpenVPN client, it is different interface, so probably some rule is missing in the iptables.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of your configuration is very incomplete, so I can only venture to **guess** a couple of things to check.

1. first, did you add the *client-to-client* directive to the server configuration? That would allow you to circumvent most *iptables*-related problems because packets would **not** pass through the usual stack, but they would be routed internally to *openvpn*.
2. Did you notice that the following rules

   ```
   Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
   target     prot opt source               destination
   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
   ```

prevent communication between the two clients? *iptables* rules are applied sequentially: whenever the first one that fits is found, further processing of the following ones ceases and the rule that applies is used. Hence, whenever a **new** packet arrives, the first rule above does not apply, the second one does, hence it is applied and the *new* packet is dropped. Thus no new connection is *ever* established.

I am **not** sure that this is all it takes to make your configuration work, but you may fist try modifying the two points above, and then come back for another iteration, **if** you have established that the above is not the sole cause of your shenanigans.

Comment: What information is missing? I can update it.

Client to client works normally. If I connect to the router from Internet by the OpenVPN or by the PPTP or I'm directly on the LAN I can normally communicate with the client. The only thing which doesn't work is the port redirect from the Internet. I tried to run tcpdump on the client directly and the request arrived, but the response back don't.